# Browser support for Lightning component hosted in Visualforce Page on Communities

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community

Based on latet Spring 17 release notes, https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-
notes/rn_lightning_apps_public.htm

I am able to display unauthenticated visualforce page which is hosting a lightning component. This is done by setting up a community and having unauthenticated visualforce page showing lightning component.

My question is , what types of browsers are supported ?

As this being a public facing community I want to make sure I understand the browser limitations of this approach.
Is the set of browsers supported by lightning component in VF page is different than set of browsers supported by plain old Visualforce Page ?

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce is a part of **salesforce classic** and hence supported browsers as per the salesforce [official docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_aloha.htm&langua_1=&type=0) are as below

1. Microsoft® Internet Explorer® version 9, 10, and 11
2. Apple® Safari® version 8.x, 9.x, and 10.x on Mac OS X
3. Microsoft® Edge for Windows® 10.

> The most recent stable versions of Mozilla® Firefox® and Google Chrome™ are also supported.

**Lightning Experience and lightning out** is supported by following
    browsers as per [official docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

1. Apple® Safari® version 9.x and 10.x on Mac OS X
2. Microsoft® Edge for Windows® 10.
3. The most recent stable versions of Mozilla® Firefox® and Google
   Chrome™ are also supported.

> **Microsoft® Internet Explorer® version 11 is retiring beginning in Summer ’16. If you’re using Microsoft® Internet Explorer® versions 9–10, you’re redirected to Salesforce Classic.**

Also there are additional restrictions in the docs I have linked to .

Comment: Hello Mohith, I have unauthenticated visualforce page which is hosting a lightning component. This is done by setting up a community and having unauthenticated visualforce page showing lightning component using ltng:allowGuestAccess interface. If anyone accesses this page using IE 10 or earlier version, how the user experience would be ? Do I need to do any browser version checks or lightning will handle it as part of graceful degradation ?